# Почему псевдоэлементы ::before и after отображаются по разному?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

подскажите кто знает, я делаю заголовок с линиями по бокам с помощью ::before и ::after, но мне интересно почему ::before находится на уровне с текстом а ::after немного отступив от заголовка, как сделать, чтоб они отображались на одном уровне, и почему так происходит, это нужно для общего развития

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот код:

```css
body {
  background: black;
}

h3 {
  margin: 100px 0;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

h3::before {
  content: "";
  background: yellow;
  height: 2px;
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
}

h3::after {
  content: "";
  background: yellow;
  height: 2px;
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
}
```

```html
<h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h3>
```

Comment: добавь картинку с ожидаемым поведением, по описанию не совсем понятно как в итоге должно выглядеть

Answer (score 1):

Делаем `padding:0 250px;` это значит что `after` и `before` будет меньше на 50px а потом эти псевдоэлементы в высоту делаем 0 а в длину `200px` и `left:0;` для after и `right:0;` для `before` но оба `top:50%`

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100vh;
  background: yellow;
}

h1 {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 250px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: table;
  margin: 30px auto;
}

h1:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 4px;
  height: 50%;
  border-top: 4px solid red;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
}

h1:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 4px;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 4px solid red;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
}
```

```html
<h1><span>lorem ipsum sit</span></h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

Если вам нужно в вашем коде after двинуть используйте `right: 0`
Вот тоже вариант, так чтобы не задумываться о том, что линии по длине доходят до конца и без падингов. Но кон не универсален, если фон картинкой будет.

```css
body {
  background: black;
}

h3 {
  margin: 100px 0;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
h3>span {
  background: black;
}

h3::before {
  content: "";
  background: yellow;
  height: 2px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<h3><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet<span></h3>
```